# How come redirect isn't working in IIS 7 ? Http > Https

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, redirect, https, windows-server-2008

I am using Server 2008 with IIS7 and have confirmed the HttpRedirectionModule is installed.
But when I define a redirect for websitexxx.com as https://websitexxx.com   I get Forbidden, access denied 403 error?

I can access the https://website.com site just fine.

Does this just not work or what?

Thank you,
James

Comment: Are you able to elaborate why and how you did the current redirection?

Comment: Have you some thing write in web.config to acheive for url redirection?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one ? [Redirecting from http to https in IIS7 (http2https Updated)](http://blogs.iis.net/sukesh/archive/2007/09/05/redirecting-from-http-to-https-in-iis7-http2https-updated.aspx) and Also [this one](http://www.jppinto.com/index.php/2009/04/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-iis-7/)

Thanks.

Comment: I had seen that.  It looks pretty good.  Maybe I will give that a try.  Thank you